# How to toggle a boolean value using Context and Hooks?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am using `ReactContext` and `Hooks` to show and hide a `Modal` on click of a button.

Following is my Context code

```
const setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility = dispatch => {
  return ({visible}) => {
    visible
      ? dispatch({type: 'enablePrivacyPolicyModalVisibility'})
      : dispatch({type: 'disablePrivacyPolicyModalVisibility'});
  };
};
```

And the reducer code for the same is something as follows

```
case 'enablePrivacyPolicyModalVisibility':
      return {...state, ...{enablePrivacyPolicy: true}};
case 'disablePrivacyPolicyModalVisibility':
      return {...state, ...{enablePrivacyPolicy: false}};
```

Some setup code in my class

```
const {state, setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility} = useContext(Context);
  const [privacyVisibility, setPrivacyVisibility] = useState(false);
```

on click of button I am calling the following code

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setPrivacyVisibility(true);
          console.log(`${privacyVisibility}`);
          setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility({privacyVisibility});
        }}.....
```

As you can see I am console logging the `privacyVisibility` value but it is always false which I fail to understand

Following is my code in the component to hide or show the Modal

```
{state.enablePrivacyPolicy ? (
        <SettingsPrivacyModal visible={true} />
      ) : (
        <SettingsPrivacyModal visible={false} />
      )}
```

The Modal code is proper as I have tried setting default value to true just to check if modal is visible then it works, but on click of button press the state value does not change and I am not able to see the modal as the value is always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the `onPress` callback:

```
onPress={() => {
    const privacyVisibility_new = !privacyVisibility;

    console.log( privacyVisibility_new );

    setPrivacyVisibility( privacyVisibility_new );
    setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility( privacyVisibility:privacyVisibility_new );
}}
```

When the cycle reaches the callback `privacyVisibility` has the default which is `false`. I think you are assuming that once `setPrivacyVisibility` is called, the `privacyVisibility` variable will have the new value in that same cycle; but it won't have the updated value until the component renders again.

---

`setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility` doesn't seem to be correct. I am not sure where is dispatch exactly, but assuming it is at the same level as the function you can simply use it inside.

```
const setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility = visible => {
    if ( visible ) {            
        dispatch({ type: "enablePrivacyPolicyModalVisibility" });
    } else {
        dispatch({ type: "disablePrivacyPolicyModalVisibility" });
    }
};
```

---

You might want to simplify your reducer and send directly the `visible` value:

```
const setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility = visible =>
    dispatch({ type: "setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility", payload: visible });
```

.

```
case 'setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility':
    return { ...state, is_privacyPolicy_visible: action.payload };
```

Comment: In setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility I am getting can't find variable dispatch

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error was simple. I am using the visible parameter as props in setPrivacyPolicyModalVisibility but while setting I am passing prop of different name

Thanks to @Alvaro for pointing me in the right direction